# jquery pull textarea values based on which checkboxes were checked

Tags: php, jquery, loops, checkbox, textarea

I'm working on a project that involves returning the id of the checkboxes chosen as well as the text in the corresponding textarea fields for those chosen checkboxes. The data is dynamically displayed and so far my jquery pull of both the checkboxes and textareas work:

```
    var noteList = $("textarea[name='revokeNotes']").map(function(){
            return this.value;
    }).get().join();
    var revokeList = $("input[name='revoke']:checked").map(function(){
            return this.id;
    }).get().join();
```

but I'm getting back all of the notes fields and I'm uncertain how to best iterate through them to find the proper notes as their ids aren't sequential but rather based on their id in the table they are being pulled from. The last version of the display code is below:

```
<td><textarea name=\"revokeNotes\" id=\"".$v["id"]."\" cols=\"30\"rows=\"3\">".$v["notes"]."</textarea></td>
<td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"".$v["id"]."\" name=\"revoke\" value=\"".$v["id"]."\" /></td>
```

Is there a way to reach my goal from this state or should I be using another jquery function, similar to .map()? I thought about using the id field from the checkboxes to iterate through the selected notes and pushing them into an array but I'm not sure 1) if that will work and 2) how to do that.

I need the data back in some form either an array or something I can explode on in php to create an array as I'm passing one value in ajax as there is no set maximum or minimum number of rows that will be displayed per user. Map was working until I threw some commas at it. Extra points for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var noteList = $.map(
                 $("textarea[name='revokeNotes']").filter(function() {
                      return $(this).closest('td')
                                    .next('td')
                                    .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
                                    .is(':checked');
                  }), function(el) {
                          return el.value; 
               }).join();
```

Answer (score 1):

adeneo's answer is great, I'd just propose the following improvements:

- If possible use class selectors (like '.revoke-notes-area') since those are faster than DOM + attr selectors
- Assuming this is a table and there is one textarea checkbox combo per row, you can traverse the tree to the closest `<tr>` a decouple the JS from depending that the checkbox comes after the text area in the DOM.

  ```
  var filterMethod = function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.revoke-checkbox').is(':checked');
  };
  var mapMethod = function(el) {
    return el.value;
  };

  var nodeList = $.map($('.revoke-notes-area').filter(filterMethod), mapMethod);
  ```

There's no reason you cannot or should not put the filter and map methods inline, I just split them out into variables so it's easier to read here.

You can check out my codepen here: http://codepen.io/aaron/pen/eIpby.